# Interactive Email Page in WebStudio

Tags: marketing-cloud, interactive-email

I have recently started working with Interactive Email Forms in the Marketing Cloud.

There is one thing about the functionality though, which I do not understand yet. Why do we need to build an "Interactive Email Page" instead of a normal Landing Page in WebStudio?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an Interactive Email Page it has an Email Form Block which is needed to add the data to the Data Extension.  You will need to configure this block for this feature to work correctly. You can add additional block types to this page to design it to your use case

Reference this page '[Interactive Email Form FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_interactive_email_form_faq.htm&type=5)'

> Upon submitting, the user is directed to a CloudPages Interactive Email page. If the submission contains errors, like incomplete required fields or undefined minimum and maximum character requirements, the recipient receives resolution messages to correct the form and resubmit. If the submission is valid, the recipient receives a response page message. You build the CloudPages Interactive Email page before selecting it in the Email Form block.